# how to add bulk category assign option in update product attribute Magento

Tags: magento, admin, categories, product, assign

HI i need to assign multiple products a same categories. I have check that under update product attributes in admin but unfortunately there is no option for this. There.
Can any body suggest me how can i add that functionality in admin.

please check this screen-shot

> http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a92v48t1b
>
> http://awesomescreenshot.com/09a2v4id8c

Answer (score 1):

"i need to assign multiple products a same categories."

If you want to do this. you have to go to category edit.

1. Catalog -> Manage Categories
2. Select a category
3. Click on Category Products tab (on top)
4. On very first column select any (there you see Yes, No and Any option)
5. Click on Search. You will see list of products.
6. Select products to assign to that category.

Comment: but i need to assign multiple categories and other values at same time

Comment: Use Magmi for easy editing of bulk products. You can assign multiple categories to multiple products in the CSV. Magmi is super fast too. If you want in Admin only, check out some extensions or write your own module.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to bulk ***change*** / ***replace*** the category of products (with or without an existing category) to a new category "Expired". I created a CSV with the following fields:

```
sku,_store,_category
194337,,Expired
106025,,Expired
```

I then used System > Import and for Import Behaviour selected "Replace existing complex data". Select your csv file and away you go. Remember a re-index is required.

If you wish to wanted to bulk ***add*** a first or further category to products, create the same file as above but for Import Behaviour select "Append complex data". I.e. if a product had been in Category: "TVs" and you use "Append complex data" with the above file, it would now be in both Categories: "TVs" and "Expired".